# Physics of electronic paper displays

Tags: electrostatics

Electronic paper displays are used in book readers such as the Kindle. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_paper)  on the technology gives a description of the physics that seems garbled, probably both because there are several different versions of the technology and because they were reusing drawings that didn't necessarily correlate with the version of the technology being discussed.

One of the basic assumptions that seems to go into this is that the particles are electrically charged. How do they acquire this charge? Is it just triboelectricity? My experience with rubbing balloons on fur, etc., would make me think that this effect would be transient and hard to reproduce.

I also don't understand why the display persists when the voltage is cut off. Wouldn't the state of electrostatic equilibrium be one in which the positive and negative materials were uniformly intermixed?

Answer (score 0):

The Kindle uses an electrophoretic display, an optical diffuser, lightguide and scattering layers, capacitive touch sensing.

For driving the pixels, it uses a thin film transistor array on the back.

The black and the white particles are permanently charged.

> > The pigment layer contains fluid-filled microcapsules with charged
> >     black and white pigment particles. The capsules are sandwiched between a transparent
> >     ground plane and thin film transistor (TFT) driven pixel electrodes unseen below the pigment
> >     layer.
> >
> > While the display state, white/black/gray, is static with the power removed, the pigment
> >     particles exhibit Brownian motion. The particles are held in a semi-permanent potential
> >     well, but they are still free to move somewhat within the liquid.

Please see here:

https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1605/1605.05174.pdf

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really answer either of the main questions I asked.